# How to create a transparent panel over a pdf to draw on using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, graphics, mouseevent, line

Im trying to write a small application to find distances between few points on a pdf file, currently im stuck with getting the transparent panel to work

[image: Image of the Application]

> XY,CD lengths are known,calculate xc and dy using pixel position (eg. xc = 40pixels)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PP_from_PDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Portable Document Files (.PDF)|*.PDF";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.src = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

how to do i create a transparent panel over the pdf to draw lines or better yet on click at each point (x,c,d,y) to collect x axis position data to calculate distance?

any help is much appreciated.
thanks
rellik

Comment: may be you could use the opacity property?

Comment: In which control is the PDF displayed? is it in a webBrowser ?  I'm afraid these don't support the fake transparency of winforms. I believe it only can work with controls that support `DrawToBitmap`. WebBrowser doesn't. If it is another Control, test to see if it supports `DrawToBitmap`. If it doesn't you'll need to read the pixels from the screen via `CopyFromScreen`. You can display the result in a `PictureBox` and either place a `Panel` with `BackColor=Color.Transparent` over it or, simpler draw on the PB's surface itself..

Comment: Hi @TaW thank you for the response, i am using Acrobat reader Activex control to display the pdf file. i tried with transparent panel and picturebox methods non of them worked for me. i tried mouse event to get the position of the cursor too with any good result. may be i need to open the pdf as a bitmap?

Comment: If you can do that it sounds like an option. But I really think that you should be able to use CopyFromScreen to get at the pixels. Do have a look at this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994222/how-to-cache-the-image-of-the-control/26994791#26994791) to a related problem (being that one would need to display not directly accessible pixels in a control that supports GDI graphics methods..!