# How to cache the image of the control?

Tags: c#, winforms, invalidation

I have C# app, but the painting job is done within C++ project (this is how it **has** to be).

So I added to my window `PictureBox`, and passed the handle to the drawing function. It works fine.

However when the control is invalidated (I move the window outside the screen and then move it back), I get in result partially empty window. AFAIK there are two approaches for this -- repaint or cache the image.

Repainting could be costly process (the image does not change often, but processing is time consuming, think of 3d renderer), so I would like to simply cache the image.

If I remember correctly from old days of programming directly with Win32 API all it takes is to set some flags. Is it possible with WinForms? If yes, how?

Comment: If you want to display an image in a PictureBox, why not set its Image property instead of painting it on its surface? This will persist and is really what a Picturebox is meant for! You can cache the suface to a bmp with PicteureBox.DrawToBitmap()..

Comment: @TaW, because the underlying drawing function knows nothing about WinForms. It is raw Win32 code, which operates on handles (HWND).

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, not about the general idea but about the way to achieve it. Since the pixels sit on the surface you can't capture them with DrawToBitmap. You need to use `CopyFromScreen` set up to capture only the right area and then set the rsulting bitmap to be the PB's Image..

Comment: Small correction: `DrawToBitmap` doesn't work because the pixels we want are __not drawn from the Paint event__. Other than that it nicely composes all three layers of a PictureBox (BackgroundImage, Image and Control Surface)..

Comment: Send `STM_SETIMAGE` message. I believe `picturebox` is a static control in win32 so it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but this flag is for sending bitmap, I am looking for something else -- DO_NOT_INVALIDATE. So the Windows would know, not to erase the image from my window.

Comment: `STM_SETIMAGE` message is send **once**. It is like *pictureBox1.Image = ...*. You set also `SS_BITMAP` to your picturebox. As for the *DO_NOT_INVALIDATE* flag, how the area of the control that is un-covered going to be painted? You need to let the system invalidate the control.

Comment: My purpose is a bit different -- I redraw the picture when the new data are coming. Otherwise it is a still image. So I don't need really a repaint after the window is clipped, only when there are new data to display. Thus I would like to set a flag "do not invalidate", because only new data can invalidate the image in my case, not because of the clipping of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
Bitmap getControlSurface(Control ctl)
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(ctl.Width, ctl.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        Point pScreen = PointToScreen(ctl.Location);
        g.CopyFromScreen(pScreen, Point.Empty, ctl.Size);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

If you know when the surface has been refreshed you can use it like this:

```
 if ( pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
 pictureBox1.Image =  getControlSurface(pictureBox1);
```

The only catch is that the `PictureBox` actually must be **completely visible** on the screen!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful. I will keep this question a bit longer open in case some W32 ninja comes up with single flag :-) I hope it is OK with you.

Comment: Me ninja, me no problem ;-)